# WoeUSB error when writing to disk

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, ntfs

I'm getting this error when I try to write a Windows 10 ISO file onto my 32GB USB:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v3.3.1
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdb...
/dev/sdb: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (dos): 55 aa
/dev/sdb: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Ensure that /dev/sdb is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdb...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day.
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.4’.
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb2': No space left on device
1025+0 records in
1024+0 records out
524288 bytes (524 kB, 512 KiB) copied, 0.219326 s, 2.4 MB/s
The command "dd if="${download_directory}/uefi-ntfs.img" of="${uefi_ntfs_partition}"" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1654797707_9050"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```